# jq: from one json input, construct multiple rows of tsv using an expression against the keys?

Tags: json, dynamic, key, jq

Using `jq` I can extract the data in this simple way as follows:

```
find . -name '*.jsonl' | xargs -I {} jq '[.data.Item_A_Foo.value, .data.Item_A_Bar.value] | @tsv' >> foobar.tsv
find . -name '*.jsonl' | xargs -I {} jq '[.data.Item_B_Foo.value, .data.Item_B_Bar.value] | @tsv' >> foobar.tsv
find . -name '*.jsonl' | xargs -I {} jq '[.data.Item_B_Foo.value, .data.Item_B_Bar.value] | @tsv' >> foobar.tsv
...
# and so on
```

But this seems pretty wasteful.  Is there a more advanced way to use JQ, and perhaps:

- Filter for `.data.Item_*_Foo.value, .data.Item_*_Bar.value`
- OR chain these rows in a single `jq` expression (reasonably readable, compact)

```
# Here is a made up JSON file that can motivate this question. 
# Imagine there are 100,000 of these and they are larger.

{
  "data": 
  {
    "Item_A_Foo": {
       "adj": "wild",
       "adv": "unruly",
       "value": "unknown"
    },
    "Item_A_Bar": {
       "adj": "rotund",
       "quality": "mighty",
       "value": "swing"
    },
    "Item_B_Foo": {
       "adj": "nice",
       "adv": "heroically",
       "value": "medium"
    },
    ... etc. for many Foo's and Bar's of A, B, C, ..., Z types
    "Not_an_Item": {
      "value": "doesn't matter"
    }
}
```

And the goal is:

```
unknown, swing # data.Item_A_Foo.value, data.Item_A_Bar.value
medium, hit # data.Item_B_Foo.value, data.Item_B_Bar.value
whatever, etc. # data.Item_C_Foo.value, data.Item_C_Bar.value
```

Comment: It'd be easier if you share a JSON snippet (example) with your actual structure, so that people can better provide suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details of your requirements are unclear, but you could proceed along the lines suggested by this jq filter:

```
  .data
  | (keys_unsorted|map(select(test("^Item_[^_]*_Foo$")))) as $foos
  | ($foos | map(sub("_Foo$"; "_Bar"))) as $bars
  | [ .[$foos[]].value, .[$bars[]].value]
  | @tsv
```

The idea is to determine dynamically which keys to select.

Comment: I think this gives me enough grammar to get to the answer.  I have a feeling `jq` will "click" soon, but I don't quite get why things work and don't work atm.

Comment: @Chris - Regarding the "clicking" - I'd be interested to know whether the short introduction I wrote (https://github.com/pkoppstein/jq/wiki/A-Stream-oriented-Introduction-to-jq) helps at all.